# c# compilation - New instance with paramters vs. New instance with subsequent attribution

Tags: c#

Apologies if this is an obvious one, I did not know what to put in to google to find an answer!

If I create an instance of a class:

```
var x = new PersonClass()
{
    Name = "Jim",
    Age = 40,
};
```

Does this compile the same as the below?

```
var x = new PersonClass();
x.Name = "Jim";
x.Age = 30;
```

And if not - is there a tangible effect on performance?

I guess what I really want to know is - is there any benefit to instancing a class and filling all its properties other than syntax sugar?

Comment: the first approach is called an [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link - so it says "the compiler processes object initializers by first accessing the parameterless instance constructor and then processing the member initializations." - that to me sounds like the 2nd method is exactly the same.

Comment: They both result in the same compiled code.

Comment: In your first example you can skip the `()` and do `var x = new PersonClass { ...`

Comment: It depends on how the properties are defined. For `{ get; set; }` properties it is just syntactic sugar. For `{ get; init; }` properties you can only use the initializer syntax to set the value once.